# How to send the mail with attachment through SMTP using iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, email, smtp

Im new to Iphone develoment can any one helpme in getting sample code in send the mail with attachment through SMTP using iphone.

i have tried the sample code from this following URL

http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code to attach file with mail.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Hello"];


// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];  
[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

// Attach an image to the email
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myFile"];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"Message body : my first email sending ";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we send attachments with our mail messages *(the following attaches a jpeg and assumes fileName has been set elsewhere to a location within your bundle, but really any NSData object will work however you initilize it as long as you set your mimeType correctly)*:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"Some Message" isHTML:YES];
[mailViewController setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[mailViewController addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName] mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"PrettyPicture.jpg"];
[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
[mailViewController release];
```